# Index link does not show in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using GridMVC in a application and need to have the column ID be clickable to display a javascript model dialog.  I have it working for Edit but that is because the Edit label is display for each row.

My code:

```
   @Html.Grid(Model).Named("watcherListGrid").Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.task_id).Titled("ID").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Sortable(false).RenderValueAs(ad =>
        {
            return @<a href="#" , onclick="ViewDetails('@ad.task_id');return false;"></a>;
        });
        columns.Add(c => c.task_name).Titled("Name");
        columns.Add(c => c.client).Titled("Client");
        columns.Add(c => c.email).Titled("Email");
        columns.Add(c => c.ftp_server).Titled("Server");
        columns.Add(c => c.ftp_username).Titled("User");
        columns.Add(c => c.ftp_method).Titled("Method");
        columns.Add(c => c.ftp_method_description).Titled("Description");
        columns.Add(c => c.ftp_dir).Titled("From Directory");
        columns.Add(c => c.local_dir).Titled("To Directory");
        columns.Add().Titled("Action").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Sortable(false).RenderValueAs(ad =>
            {
                return @<a href="#" , onclick="EditWatcher('@ad.task_id');return false;">Edit</a>;
            });
    }).WithPaging(15).Sortable(true).Filterable(false)
```

The first column ID shows a blank.  Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Edit works with 'columns.Add()' but the id doesn't with columns.Add(c => c.task_id)?

Comment: Yes the edit works and word edit shows up for each row.  But I need the actual ID value to show up for first column..